# Facebook: sharing SWF on the web via URL redirection doesn't work well

Tags: facebook, redirect

I'm using URL Redirection method to share SWF to FB. Here's documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ URL Redirection section. I pass app_id, caption, link, description, source and picture params. It used to work sometime ago but now doesn't. I whitelisted IP of application server in FB application settings but it doesn't help. My SWF is located under HTTPS. I compared params when YouTube does the same kind of sharing with mine, try diff order of params. Nothing.

From a website I have link to https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=140513466110452&link=https%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Fcollections%2F505694-rihanna-unapologetic&display=popup&&name=Unapologetic&caption=Unapologetic&description=some&picture=https%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Finprodicon_cover%3Ficpn%3D00602537246861%26width%3D200&source=https%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Fassets%2Fwidget%2Fplayer.swf%3Fdomain%3Dmenyou.com%26collectionID%3D505694&ref=share&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Ffacebook%2Fredirect_uri (link is working, app_id is correct, so you could try. For me everything matches docs. It used to work) when user is following that link, he see share dialog and is able to post, everything seems to be fine. It posts to timeline of currently logged user in FB as expected.

When I go to my news feed in FB I see only caption and description ( i.stack.imgur.com/dstg7.png ) (no preview image with "play" button on it like SWF usually has). When I go to my profile in FB and follow "comment" link there ( i.stack.imgur.com/TO6iX.png ), popup appears with preview image and with "play" button. SWF works correctly there but not in the "news feed" section of FB

Comment: Seems to be a long-running bug, I have seen it reported by various people for over half a year now. Circumstances seem to be quite unclear – what works for one user/on one page, does not for others, even using the same code and objects sometimes. I’d suggest you subscribe to one of the bug reports, f.e. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/553765594708568/

Comment: Is there a work around? I'm trying to share a link to my page with a playable video. It works on the timeline but not on the news feed, as described above. Does using the JS API avoid the bug? I know I've seen and shared videos that work in both places as just a facebook user.

Comment: I've added a separate page with meta tags like og:video, og:title
This link works via http 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=140513466110452&source=https%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Fassets%2Fwidget%2Fplayer.swf%3Fdomain%3Dmenyou.com%26hash%3DF9Tt8ioqbnxIFY7t43IFOA%3D%3D%26collectionID%3D570454%26skipSSL%3Dtrue&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Finprodicon_cover%3Ficpn%3D825646320806%26width%3D200&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Ffacebook%2Fredirect_uri&caption=Br%C3%B6der&link=http%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Fcollections%2F570454-linus-svenning-bruder%3Ffb%3Dtrue&description=

Comment: but not via https
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=140513466110452&source=https%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Fassets%2Fwidget%2Fplayer.swf%3Fdomain%3Dmenyou.com%26hash%3DF9Tt8ioqbnxIFY7t43IFOA%3D%3D%26collectionID%3D570454&picture=https%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Finprodicon_cover%3Ficpn%3D825646320806%26width%3D200&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Ffacebook%2Fredirect_uri&caption=Br%C3%B6der&link=https%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Fcollections%2F570454-linus-svenning-bruder%3Ffb%3Dtrue&description=

link param uses page with meta data via http and https.

Comment: but most doesn't work at all like the initial link

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=140513466110452&source=https%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Fassets%2Fwidget%2Fplayer.swf%3Fdomain%3Dmenyou.com%26hash%3DF9Tt8ioqbnxIFY7t43IFOA%3D%3D%26collectionID%3D570458%26skipSSL%3Dtrue&picture=http%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Finprodicon_cover%3Ficpn%3D825646322824%26width%3D200&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Ffacebook%2Fredirect_uri&caption=Shot%20Me%20Down%20(feat.%20Skylar%20Grey)&link=http%3A%2F%2Fmenyou.com%2Fcollections%2F570458-david-guetta-shot-me-down-feat-skylar-grey%3Ffb%3Dtrue&description=

Comment: with JS API the same situation, some are shared some aren't